# hasMany relation in Ember data finds no relations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data 0.14.

I have this data:

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 185588,
    "name": "USB MIDI Adapter"
  },
  "images": [
    {
      "url": "google.com",
      "product_id": 185588
    },
    {
      "url": "google.com2",
      "product_id": 185588
    }
  ]
}
```

And these models:

```
App.Image = DS.Model.extend({
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    product_id: DS.belongsTo('App.Product')
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    images: DS.hasMany('App.Image') 
});

DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Product', {
  images: { embedded: 'always' }
});
```

But I cannot get the relation to work, the "images" on product is empty. Isn't this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Can you update your question, to show your version of ember-data? There is some break changes from 0.14 to 1.0.0-beta.x, and can confuse people using a wrong version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed the data inside of `images` array:

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 185588,
    "name": "USB MIDI Adapter",
    "images": [{
      "id": 1,
      "url": "google.com",
      "product_id": 185588
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "url": "google.com2",
      "product_id": 185588
    }]
  }          
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/TEgK7/ (Using Ember Data 0.14)

Comment: Yes, you are right @kingpin2k. I asked him to update the question with the current version. Probably is 0.14 or 0.13 because of the Adapter.map(...)

Comment: I'll try to upgrade to 1.0.0 beta, should I then use kingpin2k's method with a separate object and link with id:s?

Comment: I have upgraded to v1.0.0-beta.3-4-g169793e and now the solution from @kingpin2k works. I have an edit page for this product model and I have `{{#each images}}{{input type="text" value=url}}<br>{{/each}}` to edit the images. I have a save action where I run `var product = this.modelFor('productEdit'); product.save();`. The image's url updates with the data binding, but the PUT the save action sends to /products does not include the image array and it does not send a separate PUT to the image object. How do you persist these related models?

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the mappings from the product, embedded was disabled due to issues for the time being.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 185588,
    "name": "USB MIDI Adapter",
    "images":["imageid1", "imageid2"....]
  },
  "images": [
    {
      "id": "imageid1",
      "url": "google.com",
      "product_id": 185588
    },
    {
      "id": "imageid2",
      "url": "google.com2",
      "product_id": 185588
    }
  ]
}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/40/edit

Comment: I tried this, but I still get no relation (the Ember stuff is unchanged except I removed the embedded thing): `{
  "product": {
    "id": 185588,
    "name": "2NY USB MIDI Kabel / Adapter - IN och UT",
    "images": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  "images": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "url": "google.com",
      "product_id": 185588
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "url": "google.com2",
      "product_id": 185588
    } ] }`

Comment: your has many and belongsto should just be image/product, what version of ED are you using?